# How can we create RSS Feed in WordPress / Joomla?

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla, rss, feed

I have a requirement from client to generate RSS Feed for Posts and Articles.

Kindly provide some good Plug-ins and components for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for **FeedGator** component. Free and very intuitive!